# Flatten a rotated object on Sketch

Tags: sketch-app

I have rotated an object with Sketch.
But, the old frame is still visible.

[image]

I would like to flatten it, so that in a way, I only see the outline of the object and not the old frame.

Possible?

Answer (score 3):

The closest you can get is to rotate the shape back to it being upright, flatten it again, then rotate it back.

A little demo:

[image: In Sketch, rotating a flattened shape to get the bounding box to actually match the shape.]

Comment: Also, if your object is a group and the Flatten command isn't available, you can ungroup it, then Flatten, then re-group them.